Removing trustlines
In March 2021, 2 centus trustlines were added on my lovstr wallet and two days later I see options were set to add 2 signers. Those 2 signers happen to have the same addresses as the trustlines. Ever since then I have not been able to withdraw my xlm as it asks for more signatures. I would like to know how this is possible and whether there is sone way I can remove those trustlines or change the weights of signers?
